# What is the best way to remove all subviews from you self.view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit

I was thinking maybe something like this might work:

```
for (UIView* b in self.view.subviews)
{
   [b removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I want to remove every kind of subview. UIImages, Buttons, Textfields etc.

Comment: That will work. You might have to do it kind of recursively if you have several tiers of subviews... or maybe not. I'm not sure what you want to do this for.

Comment: That works? I thought that `b` would be promptly removed from the `subviews` array, causing a mutation within a fast enumeration loop, which is forbidden.

Comment: @Mazyod check subviews property: @property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *subviews   - it is declared as copy, so when we are deleting subviews we do not modify that array (cause it's a copy).

Comment: @Max: That's incorrect. The `copy` specifier means that it makes a copy _when set_; nothing is specified about getting. It is quite likely that a copy is returned, but that's not part of the property definition.

Comment: @W'rkncacnter agree, you're right that copy keyword has nothing to do with get value (but I think it is implied).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove all subviews?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156015/remove-all-subviews)

Comment: Duplicate --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156015/remove-all-subviews

Answer (score 252, accepted):

```
[self.view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

It's identical to your variant, but slightly shorter.

Comment: What about except this – using the same method? @Mazyod

Comment: Is there any difference( by performance) between makeObjectsPerformSelector and manually loop for removing subview?

Answer (score 23):

```
self.view.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
```

Identical version in Swift.

Answer (score 7):

Swift:

```
extension UIView {
    func removeAllSubviews() {
        for subview in subviews {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this

```
//adding an object to the view
view.addSubView(UIButton())

// you can remove any UIControls you have added with this code
view.subviews.forEach { (item) in
     item.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

view is the view that you want to remove everything from. you are just removing every subview by doing forEach

Comment: Can you expand on your answer?

Comment: Isn't this mutating a collection while iterating through it?

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4+.You can make a extension to `UIView`. Call it whenever necessary.

```
extension UIView {
    func removeAllSubviews() {
        subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
    }
}
```