# Custom seperator in UITablview default cell gets shows unexpected behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Please go through these points

- Hi I have added a tableview dynamically to my code.
- I want to show my own seperator in default tableview cell.
- As default seperator has at some distance from y-axis.

I know the answer that we can use cell seperator inset property to achieve this.
But the problem I have encountered something strange.

```
DropDownTbl=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(BookTypeTxt.frame.origin.x, BookTypeTxt.frame.origin.y+BookTypeTxt.frame.size.height, BookTypeTxt.frame.size.width-11, height)];
DropDownTbl.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
DropDownTbl.tag=98;
DropDownTbl.delegate=self;
DropDownTbl.dataSource=self;

[self.settingView addSubview:DropDownTbl];
[DropDownTbl reloadData];
```

And in my tableview cell I have added seperator in this style , problem is in this way seperator view gets added twice as displayed in the given image

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text=[BookTypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:15.0f];
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,cell.contentView.frame.size.height-1, DropDownTbl.frame.size.width, 1)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];

cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];

return cell;
```

[image]

So I decide to add the linview in cell == nil parenthesis

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,cell.contentView.frame.size.height-1, DropDownTbl.frame.size.width, 1)];
    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];
}

cell.textLabel.text=[BookTypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:15.0f];
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];

return cell;
```

In this way my seperator gets disappeared when ever cell is reused. I just want to know why this happens?

Comment: did you remove cell's default seperator?

Comment: Remove your particular view  before adding it cell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005540/how-to-remove-sub-views

Answer (score 1):

This issue is generate because `cellForRowAt` called multiple times when you scroll your TableView everytime this code add new line in cell `contentView`.

Try this.

```
[[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5] removeFromSuperview];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

}

UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,cell.contentView.frame.size.height-1, tableView.frame.size.width, 1)];
lineView.tag = 5;
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];
```

Comment: But in second way , cell line gets disappeared when cell is reused.

Comment: Basically I want to know why this happens ? We are reusing the cell with custom seperator but it disappears. I don't want to know how to achieve this.

Comment: Why we have to remove from superview and add again.

Comment: @HimanDhawan, It definitely works. i have tried that and then let you know.